# Resolve Flutter dependencies in Local Git

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

in Flutter, as in https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#git-packages, we can depend on *unpublished* packages, meaning code files exist locally or in git. In git, they can be identified not only by their paths but also by the needed commit (by branch or label).

I need to support a process of two stages. first pulling the code, and then building it. i.e., we cannot pull from remote git while building.

I think about pulling from git **with the history** and that the dependencies will be resolved from the **local** git.

Another alternative is that in pulling the code, manually resolve and pull the needed branches to the local folder.

Should the first alternative work?
Does Flutter support our usecase?